# Empty interfaces and abstract class enforce structure

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

I've been looking into empty interfaces and abstract classes and from what I have read, they are generally bad practice. I intend to use them as the foundation for a small search application that I am writing. I would write the initial search provider and others would be allowed to create their own providers as well. My code's intent is enforce relationships between the classes for anyone who would like to implement them.

Can someone chime in and describe if and why this is still a bad practice and what, if any alternatives are available.

```
namespace Api.SearchProviders
{
    public abstract class ListingSeachResult
    {
        public abstract string GetResultsAsJSON();
    }

     public abstract class SearchParameters
     {
     }

     public interface IListingSearchProvider
     {
         ListingSeachResult SearchListings(SearchParameters p);
     } 
  }
```

Comment: This might be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what would an empty class be useful for? it's completely useless. Remove it and have your method expect an `object`.

Comment: How are you planning to use `p` in `SearchListings`? Are you sure you don't want something in that empty interface/class? If you really do, I'd go with an empty interface, not an empty abstract class, so that you still have the option of inheriting from something else.

Comment: I don't agree with @HighCore, but I would not use an empty abstract class. Instead I would use an (empty) Interface to allow to derive from an existing class but still force to use a class designed for the SerachProvider.

Comment: @RolandBär What benefit do you get from an empty interface?  How would you use a reference to an object implementing that interface any differently than you would use a reference of type `object`?

Comment: @cdhowie Just using `object` in the signature of the function implies that i can pass any object to this function. From the description of the OP I assume that he will try to cast this parameter to a more specific one. The risk of a non-matching parameter will therefore be smaller if the interface is requested.

Comment: @RolandBär Using an empty interface implies that you can pass any object implementing that interface, and that isn't true either.

Comment: @cdhowie You are right, but I prefer to choose from a limited amount of possible classes, and not to find the right from an (almost) unlimited amount. Using generics would, of course, be better.

Comment: @RolandBär To a degree.  However, consider that the method itself doesn't care about the interface.  You are doing this for the benefit of the caller, so that using a wrong type would raise a compile-time error.  But you can still use a wrong type with an empty interface.  In practice the pool of wrong types will be smaller, but you're still not safe.  I'd choose instead to properly use polymorphism.  If that's not possible, using `object` is cleaner from a design perspective.

Comment: @RolandBär : "force to use a class designed for the SerachProvider"?! How exactly does this (empty) interface impose ANY kind of contract on the class design?

Answer (score 1):

Empty classes and interfaces are generally only "usably useful" as generic constraints; the types are not usable by themselves, and generic constraints are generally the only context in which one may use them in conjunction with something else useful.  For example, if `IMagicThing` encapsulates some values, some implementations are mutable, and some aren't, a method which wants to record the values associated with an `IMagicThing` might be written something like:

```
void RecordValues<T>(T it) where T:IImagicThing,IIsImmutable {...}
```

where `IIsImmutable` is an empty interface whose contract says that any class which implements it and reports some value for any property must forevermore report the same value for that property.  A method written as indicated could know that its parameter was contractually obligated to behave as an immutable implementation of `IMagicThing`.

Conceptually, if various implementations of an interface will make different promises regarding their behaviors, being able to combine those promises with constraints would seem helpful.  Unfortunately, there's a rather nasty limitation with this approach: it won't be possible to pass an object to the above method unless one knows a particular type which satisfies all of the constraints, and from which object derives.  If there were only one constraint, one could cast the object to that type, but that won't work if there are two or more.

Because of the above difficulty when using constrained generics, it's better to express the concept of "an `IMagicThing` which promises to be immutable" by defining an interface `IImmutableMagicThing` which derives from `IMagicThing` but adds no new members.  A method which expects an `IImmutableMagicThing` won't accept any `IMagicThing` that doesn't implement the immutable interface, even if it happens to be immutable, but if one has a reference to an `IMagicThing` that happens to implement `IImmutableMagicThing`, one can cast that reference to the latter type and pass it to a routine that requires it.

Incidentally, there's one other usage I can see for an empty class type: as an identity token.  A class need not have any members to serve as a dictionary key, a monitor lock, or the target of a weak reference.  Especially if one has extension methods associated with such usage, defining an empty class for such purpose may be much more convenient than using `Object`.